# javascript syntax - passing variable to function

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
var testvar = "something";

//only one of the following 3 lines were uncommented while testing:
var myinsert = '<span class="green myCursor" 
                   onClick="getproblemsadmin(testvar)">
                   Test
                </span>'; //doesn't pass testvar to function

var myinsert = '<span class="green myCursor" 
                   onClick="getproblemsadmin(\'testvar\')">
                   Test
                </span>'; //doesn't pass testvar to function

var myinsert = "<span class='green myCursor' 
                   onClick='getproblemsadmin(\"testvar\")\'>
                   Test
                </span>"; //doesn't pass testvar to function

$('.someclass').html(myinsert); //jquery works and this works (tested)
```

Is there a way to pass a variable to function like this?

Comment: Do you want the value of `testvar` at the time of creating the string and setting the HTML, or at the time of the actual onclick event execution?

Comment: at the time of creating the string. The first answer that was posted is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the value of this variable?

```
var myinsert = "<span class='green myCursor' onClick='getproblemsadmin(\""+testvar+"\")\'>Test</span>";
```

The syntax:

```
var myinsert = "string" + variable + "string";
var myinsert = 'string' + variable + 'string';
```

Comment: The value, yes. Thanks, I will try this out now.

Comment: This works, thanks! (I would edit my previous comment but I can't anymore)

Comment: [Richard's jQuery solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11484123/160971) is wiser, safer and faster than building a string, especially if that string includes JavaScript that will later be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating the span element and then binding the click event:

```
$('<span class="green myCursor">Test</span>').click(function()
{
    getproblemsadmin('testvar')
});
```

or, if you wanted to get really jQuery'esk, you could write:

```
$('<span />').addClass('green myCursor').text('test').click(function()
{
    getproblemsadmin('testvar')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you are looking for a way to pass a variable to a function which will return a constructed string containing markup code? Something like this?

```
var testvar = "something";

var myinsert = work_horse(testvar);
$('.someclass').html(myinsert);

function work_horse(testvar){
    return '<span class="green myCursor" onClick="getproblemsadmin(' + testvar + ')">Test</span>';
}​
```